# Why powershell notes me the name error?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

## This is my code

```
==============
import urllib2  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.crummy.com/software'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5)'
headers = {'User-Agent' : user_agent}
request = urllib2.Request(url,headers = headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
content = response.read()
soup = beautifulsoup(request)
print soup.body#get the body element
==============
```

## This is the error information from powersehll

```
==============
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "crawlertest.py", line 9, in <module>
soup = beautifulsoup(request)
NameError: name 'beautifulsoup' is not defined
==============
```

I tried different url, but the error is still there. help

Comment: Make sure you change `print soup.bdoy` to `print soup.body`, too.

Answer (score 1):

It's not powershell, but a python script.

Python is case-sensitive for names.

The code imported `BeautifulSoup` and used `beautifulsoup`.

```
import urllib2  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  # <--- 
url = 'https://www.crummy.com/software'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5)'
headers = {'User-Agent' : user_agent}
request = urllib2.Request(url,headers = headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
content = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(request)  # <--- FIXED to match case
print soup.body #  <--- FIXED a typo
```